# Python list comprehension : build a list from 2 lists

Tags: python, list

This code

```ptyhon
colors = ["#F1A141", "#52D987", "#12A3FF", "#FF3F94", "#564DA6"]
skills = [3, 4, 4, 2, 3]
palette = [(item for i in range(skills[index])) for (index, item) in enumerate(colors)]
```

returns no error but buggy list items

```
[<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f302eac9650>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f302eac9550>, ... ]
```

Where's my mistake ?

*Edit :* the expected output is a list with 3 `"#F1A141"` items followed by 4 `"#52D987"` items, etc.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? Is it some kind of filter?

Comment: I suggest you read about list comprehensions in order to understand why you got that output. Then look at `zip()` for a way to iterate over two lists in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generator expression: `(item for i in range(skills[index])` if you want a list of lists, you need to use `[]` inside the comprehension.

Given your desired output, it might be simpler to `zip` the two lists and avoid the `range`. Then nest the comprehension to flatten it:

```
colors = ["#F1A141", "#52D987", "#12A3FF", "#FF3F94", "#564DA6"]
skills = [3, 4, 4, 2, 3]

[c for color, n in zip(colors, skills) for c in [color] * n]
```

Produces:

```
['#F1A141',
 '#F1A141',
 '#F1A141',
 '#52D987',
 '#52D987',
 '#52D987',
 '#52D987',
 '#12A3FF',
 '#12A3FF',
 '#12A3FF',
 '#12A3FF',
 '#FF3F94',
 '#FF3F94',
 '#564DA6',
 '#564DA6',
 '#564DA6']
```